# select value to push jquery

Tags: jquery, json

**JSON 1**

```
[{
    "contactflag": "0",
    "City": "America",
    "District": "District I",
    "zipcode": "4311"
}, {
    "contactflag": "1",
    "City": "America",
    "District": "District II",
    "zipcode": "4330"
}]
```

**JSON 2**

```
[{
    "contactflag": "0",
    "City": "Japan",
    "District": "District I",
    "zipcode": "7488"
}]

for (var ii = 0; ii < address.length; ii++) {
    if (address[ii].contactflag == 1) {
        addressTab.push(address[ii].City + ", " + address[ii].District + " " + address[ii].zipcode);
    } else {
        addressTab.push(address[ii].City + ", " + address[ii].District + " " + address[ii].zipcode);
    }
}
```

I have sample JSON and my code above. What I want to do is push address into an array. My `condition is to push contact address 1 if it exist otherwise push contact address 0`. But what happens to my code above is it still pushes the `contact address 0` even if there is `contact address 1`

In example 1 :

I get `["America, District I, 4311","America, District II, 4330"]` when I only wanted to get `["America, District II, 4330"]`

How to achieve this.

***UPDATE***

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/c2y80zbx/)**

Comment: What is the value of `ii`?

Comment: sorry it is from my for loop it is `var ii = 0;` i will include the for loop @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: how about address[ii].contactflag == "1"  ?

Comment: address[ii].contactflag == 1 is always true if the value exists. use address[ii].contactflag == "1"

Comment: you do exactly the sam thing in the `if` and the `else` block.

Comment: There is no different in If and else both are same

Comment: @Adam that is why i am asking for suggestion on how to deal with it

Comment: if you want to avoid all this for loop and all, you can take a look at http://defiantjs.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that your code runs for both one for when value is `1` and one for `else`, so it pushes both values.

Solution is either remove the else part

```
for (var ii = 0; ii < address.length; ii++) {
  if (address[ii].contactflag == 1) {
    addressTab.push(address[ii].City + ", " + address[ii].District + " " + address[ii].zipcode);
  }
}
```

Now here it will just push the value when the condition is true.

or just ***empty your array***:

```js
var address = [{
    "contactflag": "1",
    "City": "America",
    "District": "District II",
    "zipcode": "4330"
  }, {
    "contactflag": "0",
    "City": "America",
    "District": "District I",
    "zipcode": "4311"
  }],
  addressTab = [];


for (var ii = 0; ii < address.length; ii++) {
  if (address[ii].contactflag == 1) {
    addressTab = []; // <-----make it empty here.
    addressTab.push(address[ii].City + ", " + address[ii].District + " " + address[ii].zipcode);
    break; // <-----add this to break;
  } else {
    addressTab.push(address[ii].City + ", " + address[ii].District + " " + address[ii].zipcode);
  }
}

document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(addressTab, 0, 4);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: wow this could me an option i didnt think of this let me check @Jai :)

Comment: if i remove the else part then only the contact address with contactflag 1 will be added. my JSON sample 2 will have a problem. give a minute while a put the code in my project :)

Comment: @guradio then i guess the `if/else` with  emptying array would be better choice.

Comment: It would not work if the first item of `address` array has the `"contactflag":"1"` and the second is `"0"`.

Comment: @Adam You are right, in that case a `break;` is required.

Comment: @Adam is this okay! now. if you feel it's fine the plz remove the downvote.

Answer (score 2):

Below should work for you

```
   for (var ii = 0; ii < address.length; ii++) {
    if (address[ii].contactflag == "1") {
        addressTab = [];
        addressTab.push(address[ii].City + ", " + address[ii].District + " " + address[ii].zipcode);
    }
   else
    {
    addressTab.push(address[0].City + ", " + address[0].District + " " + address[0].zipcode);
    }
  }
```

Comment: i still get all the address instead of the address with contactflag 1

Comment: Then there is some thing wrong in your code make console.log(address[ii].contactflag) & verify what is in it. Or show us the full code

Comment: check demo i use `"1"`

Answer (score 2):

I think, this is what you'd like to do:

```
var address = [{
    "contactflag": "0",
    "City": "Japan",
    "District": "District I",
    "zipcode": "7488"
}];

var addressTab = [];

for (var ii = 0; ii < address.length; ii++) {
    if (address[ii].contactflag === "1") {
        addressTab.push(address[ii].City + ", " + address[ii].District + " " + address[ii].zipcode);
    }
}

if (addressTab.length == 0) {
    addressTab.push(address[0].City + ", " + address[0].District + " " + address[0].zipcode);
}
```

Comment: i will check this answer give me a minute

Answer (score 0):

`address[ii].contactflag == 1` is always true if the value exists. use `address[ii].contactflag == "1"` since you have stored 1 as a string.

```
if (address[ii].contactflag == "1") {
    addressTab.push(address[ii].City + ", " + address[ii].District + " " + address[ii].zipcode);
} else {
    addressTab.push(address[ii].City + ", " + address[ii].District + " " + address[ii].zipcode);
}
```